# Class not found exception in packaged plug-in. Xtext file .ui generate

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, update-site

I'm packaging a plug-in made for me called mView. I created my plug in using xtext and it generates two files more than my original project (mView.test and mView.ui) 
I have a problem when deploying my packaged plug-in (i.e. when it is not started in a runtime workbench).

The error is:

```
Plug-in mView.ui was unable to load class org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MViewExecutableExtensionFactory. 

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in mView.ui was unable to load class org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MViewExecutableExtensionFactory.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MViewExecutableExtensionFactory
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
...
```

I already ensured the jdk and jre compatibility and it's ok. In the part of the MANIFIEST of the plug-in, I already check the jar file that contains the plug-in classes and be listed in the Bundle-ClassPath. In the dependencies of the plug-in appears xtext and in the file built.properties is check the source folder in SourceBuild and BinaryBuild, but I can’t find it more to do. I would greatly appreciate your help.

PS: Just FYI: I package my plug-in following this turorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#p2deployplugin_overview

Comment: I already fix it. The proyects that xtext generate mView.test and mView.ui dont have the built.properties file. I copy this file of the principal proyect, paste and modify in each project. And it works!

Comment: Good that you found the solution to your own question. In order to allow others to benefit from your insight, you should post it as an answer. This is [explicitly encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here on stackoverflow.